# How can I make property fields and methods i can call from my user controls (ascx)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have made a basic ascx control which is just a panel with a couple controls.
My question is how can I create custom properties I could set for my custom control?
(I mean such as custom properties like runat, CssClass, etc...)
I would also like to be able to create methods for my ascx that I could call. I tried putting public static methods in the asc code behind file, but that's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes you can add to your user control are simply properties in your code-behind.  See Microsoft's [crash course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479309.aspx) on building custom user controls.